# PHP Business Intelligence - alternative to metabase.com

Tags: sql, business-intelligence

I am searching for an openSource self hosted Business Intelligence Tool. As sonamor pointed out [here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/31847/simple-business-intelligence-tool-for-scheduled-reports), The project metabase.com ist actually very good suited BUT - it is build on JAVA/clojure and I can't develop on that.

I am searching for something that is build on PHP. It would be greate to be able to build SQL queiries, without the SQL knowledge.

Does anyone know such tool?

Comment: You can create SQL Questions using metabase's query creator. I really suggest you to install it, as it only takes 5 mins, and play around with it.

Comment: That's https://metabase.com/ and it looks ok (+1). Be aware that there are many which do roughly the same thing, so you should examine a few and decide which is best for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I had been myself searching for this for a long time. Although the following did not suffice my use-case, probably, they might for you.

http://www.reportico.org/

https://mydbr.com/

https://www.koolreport.com/

Kool Report should be most relevant to you use-case

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at open source BI product Helical Insight ([www.helicalinsight.com](http://www.helicalinsight.com)).
It does have a simple drag drop interface with options of embeddding, SSO, row level data security, exporting, email scheduling etc. Definitely worth trying