# Software to produce graph, chart, table from an SQL query

Tags: database, graphs, charts, reporting, sql

I'm looking for a software that is capable of connecting to a MSSQL server, execute queries and produce graph, chart or table based on the result returned.

I understand that Reporting Server is able to do this but I'm looking for something simpler. Below are my requirements:

- Has an UI interface
- Has option to insert your own MSSQL query and then execute the query at specified database
- Has a database and the ability to store results from the query
- Able to generate tables, charts, graphs, etc and these elements must be customizable
- Able to schedule tasks and execute the queries on specified schedule
- Either open source or one time payment

Comment: See my reply to a similar question, about Metabase and how that can be used to create graphs https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/34883/15112

Comment: Would this be totally standalone, o do you require to embed it in a particular programming language (he asked the OP, who only ever logged in once, and is highly unlikely to ever return)?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Drupal](https://www.drupal.org) in combination with contributed module [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) (disclosure: I'm a co-maintainer of it) to query, not update, any MS SQL database table. It meets all your criteria (bullets), except possibly your scheduling requirement.

For more details about Forena, 2 types of documentation are available:

- [Community documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/2041363).
- Documentation that comes with Forena, which you can access right after install and enable of the module. Checkout the [demo site](http://drupal.placeto.be/reports) for an online example of the current:

  - **Forena documentation** - use the link 'Reporting documentation' or visit relative link /reports/help.
  - **Forena samples** - at relative link /reports/samples (these samples are fully functional, so make sure to experiment a bit with it, such as the drill downs available on the SVG Graph sample).

The 7.x-4.x version also includes a UI for either creating your reports (the WYSIWYG report editor) and/or for creating your SQL queries (the Query Builder).

Forena comes with a full suite of [Supported database connections](https://www.drupal.org/node/2041363#dbconnections) ... such as MS SQL, Oracle, Postgress or any PDO compliant variation.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) is ideal. It meets ALL your requirements. It IS simple it just requires some patience to learn it.

It is part of MS SQL so you probably already have the license and most likely it's already installed. Because it's integrated with MSSQL it is in seriously worthwhile reconsidering.

Here is all the documentation: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/create-deploy-and-manage-mobile-and-paginated-reports

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a product out there that does all of your requirements out-of-the box. For the querying, reporting and GUI stuff you might try

- Pentaho (opensource)
- Tableau (commercial)

If you have some programming skills you might try JasperReports or Eclipse BIRT together with a scheduler framework like Quartz.